# Custom Tabs are no longer displayed to guests

Tags: microsoft-teams

As of this morning Custom Tabs are no longer displayed to guests (tested from Web App). Yesterday it was still working.

I see that administration of teams has moved to a new admin panel, but I do not see a setting that reflects allowing guest users to access tabs.

I've tried readding the Custom Tab but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked again, and all tabs are displayed for guest users again.
...seems it was a bug and it was fixed by the MS Teams team.

See:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/Custom-Tabs-are-no-longer-displayed-to-guests/m-p/1047234/highlight/false#M41908